# Does curvature of spacetime depend upon the "mass" or "density" of a object?

Tags: general-relativity

Suppose we have a object with mass "M" with small density and a object with same mass "M" but different density (like a large density). Does the curvature of spacetime same for the two object with same mass but different densities?

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic but I assume you mean 2  spherically symmetrical objects and the same fixed distance in each case? Thanks

Comment: Is gravity a function of density or mass?

Comment: @ Abu sayed The answer is not that easy: "gravity" meaning space time curvature depends on the energy momentum tensor: energy density is one part of that, pressure another and maybe even more stuff like EM-Fields.

Comment: It depends. On a local scale, density variations can be  important, so google masscons on the moon, that pulled the Apollo spacecraft very slightly out of orbit, or look up the south Atlantic anomaly on earth, which causes the HST problems, because of density variations in the earth's core. On a global scale, far away from the object, mass is important. Your question implicitly assumes a soccer ball shape, but imagine if the mass was a large rectangle.  Close to it, you would notice a difference in pull, but far away it would feel like a point mass.

Answer (score 3):

To start with, as pointed out in the comments,  your question is not very precise. I will assume you are referring to spherically symmetric bodies. Then Birkhoff's theorem implies that the exterior is described by the Schwarzschild solution, so as long as we are in the exterior of both objects they are indeed equivalent. The interior will depend not only on the density but also on the internal flux of energy-momentum. There are several different known solutions that may describe the interior of a Schwarzschild star, at least according to general relativity, so spherical symmetry does not in any way imply interior equivalence. I can provide some links at a later time if you wish, otherwise I believe it is relatively easy to find for yourself.

Comment: I am not assume it spherical body,it may be any shaped object. My question is that Is curvature of spaectime proportional to mass or density?

Answer (score 1):

> I am not assume it spherical body,it may be any shaped object. My question is that Is curvature of spaectime proportional to mass or density

Look at the map below, it could be **any** shape, in this case it's a lumpy earth, not a perfect sphere. The bottom lines tells you where variations in density have affected the acceleration due to gravity.

[image]

So up close, on the ground, you are right, density variations **do** cause very very small distortions in  curvatures of spacetime compared to a completely regular sphere. But if you moved  to the distance of the moon, they would be so small that spacetime would be curved as if all the mass was at one point.

Now look at the asteroid Ida, which has a moon going around it, but it is just a lump of odd shaped rock.

[image]

That moon Dactyl is still following the curvature of spacetime produced by Ida, as if Ida was a point mass, but it's orbit will change over time, in all sorts of directions, because of the density variations of Ida. Our moon won't,  it will just slow down,  it's so far away from Earth

So the spacetime curvature produced by an object and felt by you, depend on it's mass, it's density variations and the distance you are away from it.